# Smarty template question

Tags: php, templates, smarty

i am new to smarty template and i am trying to do this.
I have a html form in the tpl file and in that form action is for a php email function email.php. I am not able to get it to work. if i have the complete code(html form + php email code) and save as a php file, it works fine.

is there any way to call the php code from email.php inside that tpl file? i am completely new and i am just making some changes on the site.

regards

Comment: accept some more answers to your questions

Comment: hi, I get your point, but i usually go and visit the answers once i am done and i vote and also accept the answers. i totally understand how one should give credit to others. thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after doing some google search, i found that i can do this way

In the tpl(ex - mail.tpl)

```
{ php }
//all php code here, in my case its the mailer
{ /php }
```

and in the form action, just give "mail.tpl" .

fyi, i designed this contact with ajax way to just do the submission in the same page without navigating.

Answer (score 0):

{php}{/php} is deprecated in Smarty V3 now